# Pilha de numero pares javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando retirar os números impares de uma pilha em uma expressão `while` javascript porem não consigo, alguém teria uma dica pra me ajudar.

Segue o código baixo:

```
var j=0, msg="";
while (j<=10){
     if(j ==10){
       msg +=j;
       break;
     }
     if(j%2 !=0){
       msg += "";
     }
    msg += j + ", ";
    j++;
  };
console.log(msg);
```

O `console.log()` me mostra os números impares também mas quero somente os pares.

Comment: Bem-vindo mr.aureli, se alguma resposta resolveu seu problema, veja nesse post porque aceitar uma resposta é importante https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é a concatenação ser feita sempre, pois está fora do `if`:

```
if(j%2 !=0){ //e devia ser ==0 para ser pares
    msg += ""; //devia estar a juntar aqui o numero aqui
}
msg += j + ", "; //e não aqui, que irá acontecer para todos
```

Devia então ficar assim:

```
if(j%2 == 0){
    msg += j + ", ";
}
```

---

A titulo de graça e ao estilo do Codegolf, mostro outra forma (menos educativa) de fazer o mesmo:

```js
let msg = [...Array(11).keys()].filter(x => x%2==0).map(x => ""+x).join(',');

console.log(msg);
```

Answer (score 3):

Considerando imprimir apenas os números pares entre 0 e 7.
Consegui seguin essa lógica:

```
function passandoPelosPares() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                            console.log('aqui eu tenho o valor de ' + i);
            }
        }
}

passandoPelosPares();
```

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi porque comparar com 10, o loop já entende que o 10 está incluso. A linha `msg += j + ", ";` deveria estar dentro da condicional `if`. Por fim, `break` não é necessário nesse caso.

Segue o código:

```
var j = 0, msg = "";
while (j <= 10) {
    if (j % 2 === 0) {
        msg += j + ", ";
    }
    j++;
}
console.log(msg);
```

**EDIT**

Comparando com o `10` para terminar com um `.`

```
var j = 0, msg = "";
while (j <= 10) {
    if (j % 2 === 0) {
        if (j === 10){
            msg += j + ". ";
        }else{
            msg += j + ", ";
        }
    }
    j++;
}
console.log(msg);
```

Comment: Ele compara com `10` para não colocar a ultima virgula.

Comment: Ah, entendi. Vou editar a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Em princípio vou corrigir sua lógica, e no final da resposta um script mais enxuto.

No seu código, quando j é impar entra na condição `if` (quando é impar) e não concatena nada, o script prossegue para a linha de baixo que está concatenando todos os valores de j.

```
  //se for impar
  if(j%2 !=0){
     //não concatena
     msg += "";
   }
   //sai do if e executa a linha abaixo, sendo impar ou par
   msg += j + ", ";`
```

> Então, faltou colocar um `else` no seu script, assim, se for impar entra no `IF` e não executa o `ELSE` e se for par não executa o `IF` e executa o `ELSE`

`if(j%2 !=0){
       msg += "";
     }else{
       msg += j + ", ";
     }`

Veja o resultado

```js
var j=0, msg="";
while (j<=10){
     if(j ==10){
       msg +=j;
       break;
     }
     if(j%2 !=0){
       msg += "";
     }else{
       msg += j + ", ";
    }
    j++;
  };
console.log(msg);
```

---

**O mesmo resultado se obtêm assim:**

```js
var j=0, msg="";
while (j<=10){
     
     //só concatena se forem números pares
     if(j%2 ==0){
        msg += j + ", ";
     }
    j++;
  };
//retira ultima virgula com ultimo espaço 
msg = msg.substr(0,(msg.length -2));
console.log(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Espero que Ajude;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var j=0, pares="", impares="";
    while (j<=10){
        //Concatena os números pares
        pares   +=  (j%2 == 0 )?j+",":"";
        //Concatena os números impares
        impares += !(j%2 == 0 )?j+",":"";
        j++;
     };
     //Remove o último caracter, no caso, a virgula final
     pares = pares.substr(0,(pares.length - 1)); 
     impares = impares.substr(0,(impares.length - 1)); 

    console.log(pares);
    console.log(impares);
</script>
```